# Как вывести на "Canvas" квадратики в случайном месте?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как сделать так, чтобы с помощью `Canvas` появлялись в случайном месте квадратики определённого размера.

Answer (score 5):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

let randomize = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

let size = 15; //размер любой, какой душе угоден

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {//5 - количество квадратиков
  let xCoord = randomize(0, 300 - size); //300 - ширина canvas
  let yCoord = randomize(0, 150 - size); //150 - высота canvas
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.rect(xCoord, yCoord, size, size);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```